# How can I set preference constants in Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to change some default user settings in Eclipse using custom plugin. There are constants that define these settings ([Constant Field Values](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/constant-values.html)) What should I do to set some of them in Plugin? For example, I want to switch on line numbers or save resources before launch (there are constants for such things) by default. How can I do that? Tried something like this, but nothing changed:

```java
 String lineNumbers = AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_LINE_NUMBER_RULER;
 EditorsUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(lineNumbers, true);
```

This question is not about finding constants tied to some settings, it's about finding an approach to change them.

I execute code in one of my Plugin classes. It looks like that:

```java
String lineNumbers = AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_LINE_NUMBER_RULER;

void initVal (String lineNumbers){   
    EditorsUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(lineNumbers, true);
    }
```

Also tried this one:

```java
IPerspectiveRegistry perspectives =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench ().getPerspectiveRegistry();

void initValues (IPerspectiveRegistry perspectives){        
        perspectives.setDefaultPerspective ("org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective");
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the correct place to set the preference. Where are you executing this code?

Comment: I've edited question, added some examples. I also thought that I misplaced this code, I tried many things but nothing worked.

Comment: If I'am wrong, where should I execute this code? It would be great if you could provide little example of changing Eclipse default settings (just one, not especially line numbers, it could be anything) using Eclipse plugin. I only need to find general approach to that matter.

Comment: Where in your plugin are you doing this? When a button is pressed? In the activator start (which probably won't work)? If you are building a RCP you can set defaults like this in the plugin_customization.ini file.

Comment: I don't provide user possibility to change this. Value is set in plugin and then it is displayed in new Eclipse instance when it's launched (or when I install this Plugin to another IDE). I used something like that for External Tools values, it worked (but there are other metods for this, like `setAttribute` ). It looks that I haven't answered to your comment properly, but I don't know what else to say. At the moment I don't tie any settings to user actions, I just define String variables and try to pass them to IDE as default values. I'll try plugin_customization.ini file, thank you.